# need help trying to run a array strcpy program

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm not sure what I need to run this code, I'm confused on the error and would greatly appreciate the assistance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

unsigned int strlen(const char s[])
{
    unsigned int n;

    for (n = 0; s[n]; n++);

    return n;
}

void strcpy(char t[], const char s[])
{
    for (int i = 0; t[i] = s[i]; i++);
}

void teststring()
{
    assert(strlen("") == 0);
    assert(strlen("A") == 1);
    assert(strlen("lime") == 4);

    cout << "valid" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    char t[2] = "";
    char s[5] = "a";
    char i[6] = "Joey";

    teststring();

    assert(strcpy(t, s) == 0);
    assert(strcpy(t, s) == 1);
    assert(strcpy(t, s) == 4);

    cout << "valid" << endl;
}
```

I keep getting an error that says void value not ignored as it ought to be.

I'm not sure what I need to do in order to get the code to run.

Comment: the function `strcpy` will never return because the for condition `t[i] = s[i]` is an assignment that will always evaluate to `true`.

Comment: Yes, it gets terminated when the end of string is reached.  `t[i]` is evaluated as a condition after it's being assigned `s[i]`.

Comment: The `strcpy` algorithm is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the main function, I think you should `assert` `strlen(t) ==` after `strcpy(t, s)`.

I would write:

```
// BTW, you wouldn't strcpy(t, t) would you?
assert(strlen(t) == 0);
strcpy(t, s);
assert(strlen(t) == 1);
strcpy(t, i);
assert(strlen(t) == 4);
```

Or, you may change `strcpy` to return `strlen` leaving the main function as is, like this:

```
unsigned int strcpy(char t[], const char s[])
{
    for (int i = 0; t[i] = s[i]; i++);

    return strlen(t);
}
```

In the `main` function, the size of `t[]` shall be larger than `s[]` and `I[]`.  You have mentioned it in your question but you didn't implement it in your code.

```
char t[2] = "";   // from this
char t[10] = "";  // to something like this
```

Answer (score 1):

You are `assert`ing that `strcpy(t, s)` returns `0` then `1` and finally `4`.

The prototype of your `strcpy` says it returns nothing: `void strcpy(char t[], const char s[])`

Nothing cannot equal anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your `strcpy` has a return type of void. I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. Nothing can only equal nothing (unless nothing is something, in which case nothing cannot equal anything).